# how to use subsonic2.1 build a query like this

Tags: subsonic

```
SELECT * FROM sometable where a=1 and (a=2 or (b=1 and c=2))
```

How can I build a query I need? (no inlinequery)

Answer (score 1):

```
DB.Select().From(sometable.Schema)    
  .Where(sometable.a).IsEqualTo(1)  
  .AndExpression(sometable.a).IsEqualTo(2)  
  .OrExpression(sometable.b).IsEqualTo(1)  
  .And(sometable.c).IsEqualTo(2);
```

Comment: your query result is 
SELECT * FROM sometable where a=1 and (a=2 ) or (b=1 and c=2)
so it's not the right answer

Comment: You should upgrade to SubSonic 2.2

Comment: thx,and i have download it, read the release notes, i want to know more diffs from 2.1 ,can you help me?

Comment: You can have a look at the release page to see what's changed http://blog.wekeroad.com/subsonic/subsonic-22-released/